# How to get a webpage displayed within another webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, iframe

I am trying to create a web-app "A" using spring-security framework. After authentication it will bring the user to a page where another web-app "B" (hosted at same/other server) is displayed within a window (achievable using iframe). The main web-app "A" takes the link address of web-app "B" from user and therefore web-app "B" should be dynamically changeable.

I have created web-app "A" having CAS authentication. After authentication it displays web-app "B" within a window using iframe, but when I try to use jQuery and Javascript to dynamically change the web-page "B", it fails.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me in this. Firstly, let me know whether I am doing it right or not, otherwise suggest me the right steps. Also let me know if there is a better way to achieve the same. See the code below.

Thanks, 
Sachin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#serverurl").attr("src", $("#Link").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Secure Page</h1>
<p>This is a protected page. You can get to me if you've been remembered,
    or if you've authenticated this session.</p>

<p><a href="../">Home</a>
<p><a href="../j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a>

<p>Enter URL: <input type="text" id="Link" value="www.google.com"></p>
<button>Show webpage</button>

<div><iframe src="http://w3school.com" id="serverurl" width="800" height="600"></iframe></div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: so what is the code that you have tried

Comment: @Satya: Please see the updated message.

Comment: Assuming Website A have been compromised and you loads Website B in a iframe. Javascript on Website A records whatever you have submitted (eg: credit card), change Website B to a similar looking Website C and submits that information out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated your example on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eZRTw/1/

So, you have two problems:

1. Your input value lacks http://. So your browser tries to open a relative path like: http://yourserver.com/www.google.com
2. If you open the browser console and click on "show webpage", you will see an error like: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`. That happens because the google server [sends a header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to avoid [clickjacking attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking).

If all the websites you want to display in the iFrame doesn't send `X-Frame-Options`, like google, just fix the first item and everything will be okay.

Comment: Thank you Renan, It seems to work on jsFiddle. I will certainly try this and let you know if it works. I appreciate your help.